# update content of master page from updatepanel in content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I need to update content of master's master page in order to update shopping cart totoal price. I have a updatepanel in content page from where user add products. How can i  update master's master contents/ label on click of button inside update panel.

Comment: Provide a public method in your master page that updates the label and the updatepanel that you can call from your content page. Remember to cast the `Master` property to the correct type of your master.

Comment: do in need to put label of master page inside update panel ?

Comment: Yes, you need if you want a partial update.

Answer (score 0):

As updatepanel async refresh updates its own area only, it is not possible to refresh another area (shopping cart total price). One solution is to add another updatepanel around shopping cart total control and refresh it from serverside code when your main update panel refreshes/

Answer (score -1):

I faced a problem like this a few days ago, I solved it with jQuery.

1. Give the total shipping label a CSS class
2. Use jQuery to call that class form the jQuery script and update it's text.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to include an example for the OP.